# Will the Google Apps Script Contacts Service (ContactsApp) still work after the People API migration?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

Google is migrating the Contacts API to the new People API beginning in June 2021. In some of my Google Apps Scripts I use the ContactsApp class from the Contacts Service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts). Will this service still will work after the migration to the new People API?

Comment: The ContactsApp service is a wrapper for the Contacts API so I suspect it to be removed on the sunset date June 15. Apps Script has an Advanced Service wrapper for the People API so you can always leverage that when migrating your code.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot There's no mention of it in the Apps Script documentation

Comment: @Cooper True. The Apps Script [Sunset Schedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset) makes no mention of it. But, based on precedence, once a deprecated API is past its sunset date, any corresponding wrappers in Apps Script (built-in or advanced) are typically removed. Better to be safe than sorry and migrate your code to the People API advanced service.

Comment: I tried get an answer from support on this very question but unfortunately they seemed to know even less about it than I did.  Because it's going to be a significant impact upon me and my clients.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion @Cooper and TheAddonDepot. I noticed the same thing with no mention of it in the documentation. It would be good to know whether there will be a corresponding wrapper for the People API. The advantage of the wrapper was that clients don't have to enable the advanced API in their Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Apps Script acts as a client to the Contacts API and will receive the same error rates as all other clients.*

#### More Information:

After the sunset of Contacts API, any errors that would be returned when trying to use it will be seen no matter how it is called - be that a client library, the Apps Script wrapper, or just HTTP requests.

Google sent out an email recently informing of the change - and this should have been received regardless of whether they are using Contacts API directly, or have Apps Script projects which use it.

At the moment it doesn't seem that there are any plans for a `PeopleService` or equivalent - but the Apps Script Advanced Services do have People API integration.

I would also urge you to make a feature request for a `PeopleService` equivalent of `ContactsService`, if you would like to see something like this implemented. You can file a feature request for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) on Google's Issue Tracker under the Apps Script Feature Request component.

Comment: As of October 2, 2023, the Class ContacApp page points to use the People API Advanced Service.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, No.  It does not still work.  I am in the middle of refactoring my code because it doesn't work anymore.

---

I am trying to get a list of contacts from Google Contacts that have a specific label and now with the migration, I have not idea how to do this.

Comment: The only way I found to do this was first find the contact group resource then grab all the people resources. So first get all the group resources with People.ContactGroups.list, loop through all of them until you match the name key with the item you want, that will give you the grp resource. Then use People.People.getBatchGet to get all of the people resources for that group.